# A very simple linear algebra question about proofing linear dependence.

Tags: linear-algebra

[image]I know the answer is linear independence, but what if the c3 in the picture is equal to 0. Does it mean the answer is linear independence?

Does it have to be one of C to be non-zero in order to be linear dependence?

[Whole video](https://www.khanacademy.org/math/linear-algebra/vectors-and-spaces/linear-independence/v/more-on-linear-independence)

Answer (score 1):

> I know the answer is linear independence, but what if the c3 in the picture is equal to 0. Does it mean the answer is linear independence?

No, the vectors only form a linearly independent set if the **only** way to make the zero vector as a linear combination of the vectors, is to take **all** of the coefficients equal to zero.

If you would have $c_3 =0$ but $c_1$ and $c_2$ still non-zero, the vectors are still linearly dependent.

---

Note: when you covered some more material, there are quicker ways of concluding this. In your case: 3 vectors - or any number over 2, for that matter - in $\mathbb{R}^2$ will always be *linearly dependent*.

Comment: if all of the coefficients are zero, is this also a solution for linear dependence?